# Can I apply for a Type D visa for Austria from Germany while holding a Type D visa in Germany?

Tags: germany, schengen, austria

I am in Germany and hold a Type D visa here. Can I apply for a Type D visa for Austria while I am here in Germany on this Type D visa?